# Grow Image Height in dependency to text element

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

Hello guys im trying to grow my image height in dependency to my
`<p>` tag the image  should be zoomend(like an overflow) and vertical centered without setting the image as `background-image:` cause i have to use an image srcSet later any suggetions?

[my example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39gqn0qa/)

> html

```
    <div class="content">
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <img src="via.placeholder.com/800X600">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

> .css

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
p{
  top: 0;
  positon: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: change `wrapper` to `content-wrapper` in CSS

Comment: without success

Comment: Check the answer and fiddle. It's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 solution to do that, that doesn't stretch the image.

`object-fit`, which doesn't have full browser support yet

```css
.content-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800X600">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
      et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or you can wrap the `img` and mimic `background-size: cover`

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qate356t/)

```css
.content-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800X600">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
      et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and at least is it possible to hold the image hight for example 200px by default if the content is empty?

Comment: @mY777 Yes, add `min-height: 200px;` to the `.content-wrapper` rule ... and it works for both given solutions

Answer (score 1):

Change all your CSS to

```
.content-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
img{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39gqn0qa/5/)

Comment: awesome is it possible to scale the image instead of stretching it?

Comment: No, we can't preserve the aspect ratio of an image when `height` and `width` are `fixed`(the above case). We can maintain the aspect ratio of an image only either `height` or `width` `fixed` and the other is `auto`.

Comment: what is about webkit-transform or something

Comment: `transform` is different. You can see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=example#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @mY777 _is it possible to scale the image instead of stretching it?_ ... Yes, that is possible and I posted an answer showing 2 ways to do that using the `img` element